# Liferay : Location of Language.properties

Tags: liferay

I am following the learning path of Liferay in the docs.

I am implementing the AlloyUI, However I got stocked because the

**docroot/WEB-INF/src/content/Language.properties**

is nowhere to be found in my package explorer, I have no **content** folder in my **src**.

Any idea where can I find this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what is exact question? Are you searching Language properties file inside some plugin ? or in liferay source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give a lot of context, but `content/Language.properties` is the default location for the resource bundles in Liferay - probably you're either developing a portlet or a hook. As you say that the directory is not there, you can just create it. It's nothing else but a java package. Then create `Language.properties` in the directory and you can use Liferay's LanguageBuilder to create the other language files (e.g. `Language_de.properties`).