# Liferay ignores my portlet's Language.properties

Tags: localization, liferay-6, portlet, properties-file

My portlet defines some GUI elements containing text labels "category" and "abbreviation":

```
    [...]
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="category"
        property="category"
    />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text
        name="abbreviation"
        property="abbreviation"
    />
    [...]
```

When rendered in a web browser, "category" shows up as "Category" (probably because the Liferay portal uses that word for its core) which is great, but "abbreviation" stays lowercase, so I [created a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31980111/liferay-location-of-language-properties) `WEB-INF/src/content/Language.properties` containing this:

```
abbreviation=Abbrevation
```

PROBLEM: Even after rebuilding and restarting the server, "abbreviation" is still shown lowercase. It seems that Liferay does not take into account my portlet's `Language.properties`.

QUESTION: What could be my problem? What did I forget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your `portlet.xml`, inside `portlet` node you should have this:

```
<resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>
```

If you can't find it we have found your problem probably (one of your problems at least)!

This line tells the portlet in which file search your custom language keys before of the core ones.

Ref: [Localizing your Portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/localizing-your-portlet)